# problem with accents in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex

I work with LaTeX under Windows 7, and I use the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[a4paper,tmargin=2.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
```

but I can't compile my file if it contains umlauts such as `é`, `è` or `à`...

Why does this happen?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your file does not have any accented character yet...

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error; Do you save your document as utf8? Please also include necessary packages and a `\begin{document}…\end{document}` that includes the accents. You include `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` twice, once is enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

You should include this two lines in your file. Try to comment the line `\usepackage[francais]{babel}`. It works for me.

Comment: Babel is probably needed by OP for proper hyphenation. Don't remove packages unless there is a clear clash.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Both two cases I comment and uncomment this line, it still works.

Comment: Unrelated: the `francais` option should be loaded with  the document class. That said, do you have `cm-super` installed?

Comment: @Bernard: Yes. I installed texlive-full on my system, so it includes `cm-super' as you said.